# Obj-c - Sort dictionaries in array by date/time?

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I'm trying to put the people (dictionaries) in my array in order by the date/time located in scheduleddate. Here's the code i'm using, but it doesn't seem to work. The people are simply returned in the same order (and not re-ordered by date/time).

My current code:

**ViewController.m**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"];

    self.sortedByTime = [self.dailySchedule sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2)
    {
        NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1[@"scheduleddate"]];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2[@"scheduleddate"]];
        return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];
    NSLog(@"Sorted Array : %@", self.sortedByTime);
    }
```

**Contained in my array, I have:**

```
{
        "first name" = Michael;
        "last name" = Levy;
        scheduleddate = "Feb 14, 2021 05:00 PM";
      
    },
        {

        "first name" = Cali;
        "last name" = Wright;
        scheduleddate = "Feb 14, 2021 10:00 AM";
  
    },
        {
         "first name" = Janine;
        "last name" = Lohr;
         scheduleddate = "Feb 14, 2021 01:00 PM";
   
    }
```

**What I want to achieve:**

```
 {
            "first name" = Cali;
            "last name" = Wright;
            scheduleddate = "Feb 14, 2021 10:00 AM";
      
        },
 {
             "first name" = Janine;
            "last name" = Lohr;
             scheduleddate = "Feb 14, 2021 01:00 PM";
       
        },

 {
            "first name" = Michael;
            "last name" = Levy;
            scheduleddate = "Feb 14, 2021 05:00 PM";
          
        }
```

Comment: You need to learn how to debug. First debugging step: is `date1` and `date2` with the correct value (to be able to sort according to it)? No. Your `dateFormat` isn't working. So `[date1 compare:date2]` return 0, so it's `NSOrderedSame`, so it's keeping the initial order.

Comment: @Larme I just realized the date format isn't working -- and after looking up the date format table, it doesn't look like I can do MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm? Is that format not customizable? E.g. I'm stuck using the ones in the Apple table?

Comment: So, if you used the correct dateFormat: `"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"`, it should work. Write `"Feb 14, 2021 05:00 PM"` above "`MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm`, add spaces to make each part above the other corresponding one: `Feb` above `MMM` etc? Which one is above `PM`?  Show how is the formatter supposed to know what to do with PM/AM? You need to tell it that after the minutes, there would be AM/PM, with `a`.

Comment: @Larme You are...the best. Thank you SO much. This was incredibly helpful. Works :)

Comment: @Larme On the note of customizing that format though, if I move the comma and do MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a - should this still work if my inputted data looks like Feb 18 2021, 05:00 PM ?

Comment: Are you the one constructing that `scheduleddate` values? If yes, use `NSDate`, not NSString, just read that date and format it for a the user, not when you are using your data.